# Javascript program throws unwanted gaps in a table output

Tags: javascript

The code:

```
function displayWelcome() {
        console.log("Welcome! \nThis program will determine the time to pay off a credit card and the interest paid based on the current balance, the interest rate, and the monthly payments made.")
    }

    function calculateminimumPaymentment(balance, minimumPaymentRate) {
        return Math.max(20, balance * minimumPaymentRate);
    }

    function displayPayments(balance, interest, minimumPayment) {

        console.log("Balance on your credit card: $" + balance.toFixed(2))
        console.log("Interest Rate: " + (interest * 100) + "%")
        console.log("Assuming a minimum payment of 2% of the balance ($20 min)")
        console.log("Your minimum payment would be: $" + minimumPayment)
        console.log("\nYear    Balance     Payment #     Interest Paid      Minimum Payment")

        var year = 1;
        var payments = 1;
        var interestPaid = 0;
        var yearChange;

        while (balance > 0) {
            yearChange = false;

            if (payments % 12 == 0) {
                year++
                yearChange = true;
            }
            interestPaid += balance * interest / 12;
            balance = Math.max(0, balance - (minimumPayment - balance * interest / 12));
            minimumPayment = Math.max(20, balance * minimumPaymentRate);
            console.log(yearChange? year: "" + "        " + balance.toFixed(2) + "      " + payments + "              " + interestPaid.toFixed(2) + "             " + minimumPayment.toFixed(2));
            payments++;
        }
    }

    var balance = 1500;
    var minimumPaymentRate = 0.02;
    var interest = 0.18;

    displayWelcome()
    var minimumPayment = calculateminimumPaymentment(balance, minimumPaymentRate);

    displayPayments(balance, interest, minimumPayment);
```

Output

```
Year    Balance     Payment #     Interest Paid      Minimum Payment
        1492.50      1              22.50             29.85
        1485.04      2              44.89             29.70
        1477.61      3              67.16             29.55
        1470.22      4              89.33             29.40
        1462.87      5              111.38             29.26
        1455.56      6              133.32             29.11
        1448.28      7              155.16             28.97
        1441.04      8              176.88             28.82
        1433.83      9              198.50             28.68
        1426.67      10              220.00             28.53
        1419.53      11              241.40             28.39
2
        1405.37      13              283.88             28.11
        1398.35      14              304.96             27.97
        1391.35      15              325.94             27.83
        1384.40      16              346.81             27.69
        1377.47      17              367.58             27.55
        1370.59      18              388.24             27.41
        1363.73      19              408.80             27.27
        1356.92      20              429.25             27.14
        1350.13      21              449.61             27.00
        1343.38      22              469.86             26.87
        1336.66      23              490.01             26.73
3
```

I don't understand how to make it so that along with the year number, it also shows the corresponding data, because when I run it now it just skips the rest and shows it again on the next row. Also would like to know how to have 1 in the first row signifying year 1. The desired output is shown below.

[image: Desired Output]

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Don't you want to display the output on a html table instead?

Comment: @funcoding No, just in the console as per the requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things to change:

1. Initialise *payments* to 0 instead of 1:

   ```
   var payments = 0;
   ```
2. Use parentheses around the ternary operator, because it does not have precedence over the `+` that follows it:

   ```
   console.log((yearChange? year: "") + "        " + balance.toFixed(2) +
       // ...etc.
   ```

As month numbers are then zero based, you might want to add one to the display of it, like so:

```
        "      " + (payments+1) +
```

Or, alternatively, move the following increment just before the `console.log`:

```
        payments++;
```

Comment: Also, a way to make the spacing more consistent would be to use a tab `\t` instead of spaces.

Comment: Also, how to make it so that the first min payment is shown as $30.00 instead of $29.85? I tried adding .15 to the console.log but it didn't work.

Comment: move `minimumPayment = ` before `balance = ` to get the `30.00` in the last column of the first line.

Comment: @trincot That did it! Appreciate the help!